# geometry inequality

Tags: geometry, inequality, triangles, geometric-inequalities

$M$ is a point in $\triangle ABC$. $AM$ intersect with $BC$ at $A_1$. $BM$ intersect with $AC$ at $B_1$. $CM$ intersect with $AB$ at $C_1$.

Proof that: $$AA_1 \times BB_1 \times CC_1 \geq 27 (MA_1 \times MB_1 \times MC_1)$$

Comment: Hint: consider areas and use AM-GM.

Comment: What are your thoughts? Write your working in the edit. Please don't think it as spoon-feeding, question taking &  answer giving website.

Answer (score 0):

Transform the ratio of sides to ratio of the areas of triangles. Then the inequality is equivalent to:

$27abc\leq(a+b+c)^3$, where $a$, $b$, and $c$ stand for the areas of three inner triangles.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Answer (score 0):

$$ \Leftrightarrow S_{AMB}\cdot S_{BMC}\cdot  S_{CMA}\le \left(\dfrac{ S_{AMB}+S_{BMC}+S_{CMA}}{3} \right )^3 = \dfrac{1}{27}S^3 $$

Answer (score 0):

By AM-GM
$$\frac{MA_1\cdot MB_1\cdot MC_1}{AA_1\cdot BB_1\cdot CC_1}=\frac{S_{\Delta BMC}}{S_{\Delta ABC}}\cdot\frac{S_{\Delta AMC}}{S_{\Delta ABC}}\cdot\frac{S_{\Delta AMB}}{S_{\Delta ABC}}\leq$$
$$\leq\left(\frac{\frac{S_{\Delta BMC}}{S_{\Delta ABC}}+\frac{S_{\Delta AMC}}{S_{\Delta ABC}}+\frac{S_{\Delta AMB}}{S_{\Delta ABC}}}{3}\right)^3=\frac{1}{27}.$$